# How to change local path for sftp in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, sftp

I need to change default local path on sftp wbond Sublime Text 2. The default path is something like this, 
c:\users\dery\appdata\local\temp\sublime-sftp-browse-1437897788\web

I need to change to this path 
D:\xampp\htdocs\web

Any idea? I've stucked

Answer (score 0):

The path you mentioned is the location for temporary files downloaded from a remote server for editing. If you want to map a local path to a remote one (for example, `D:\xampp\htdocs\web` to `/home/example.com/public_html`), add the local folder to your current Sublime project, right-click on it in the sidebar, and select **`SFTP/FTP -> Map to Remote...`**.

Please refer to the [SFTP website](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp) for complete documentation of the plugin.